# Is there a way to change the private key associated to a web3 account?

Tags: ethereum, web3js

I have a web3 account and private key with me. Lets say I have the 12 word mnuemoic too. Is there a way I can change my private key or rotate it when I want ?

If not, what should I do if my private key gets compromised. If yes, can you point me to the code or API in web3 which would help me do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An address is generated from its private key. So when you change a private key, it always results in a different address.

*Note: It's statistically possible that there are multiple private keys to the same address. There are several researches but none have found a collision (a second private key generating the same address), as the probability is extremely low - practically impossible with our current technology.*

---

If the change of address is all right for you use case, you can add a new account to the web3 instance using the `wallet.add()` function ([docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth-accounts.html#wallet-add)), or remove an account using the `wallet.remove()` function ([docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth-accounts.html#wallet-remove)).

Unfortunately web3 only works with private keys - not with mnemonic phrases. So you'll need to generate the according private key from the mnemonic using a different package. For example the [hdwallet-provider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@truffle/hdwallet-provider).

Comment: So if I have to remove an account, I will have to transfer the balance of the account to another account and then remove it I assume @Petr ?

Comment: @vizsatiz Only the information about the account is removed from your local web3 instance. But it doesn't affect the onchain balance... So assuming you have the private key backed up elsewhere, you don't need to transfer its balance out.

Comment: But as the question says my private key is compromised and I want it destroyed, out of my account. So that means I will have to right ? @Petr ?

Comment: @vizsatiz If your private key is compromised, the attacker has full access to your account. The algorithm generating an address from a private key is given, so there's no way to block the attacker (or anyone who knows the private key) from using the account.